# Can I make a sim where "water" breaks a "glass window"?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, fluid-simulation

So I want to make a sim where the camera starts in a hallway and moves towards a window at the end of it where a room is filling with water. When the room gets about halfway full or so i want the window to shatter, starting with small fractures and slowly getting bigger till it breaks. Letting out all the water in the room. Is something like that possible?

[.blend file](https://pasteall.org/blend/947a447b1ab84827b025595b579ef371) if that helps at all.

Comment: I don't think you can use a forces of fluid sim to break a glass, but there is nothing easier than fake it by using any other object to break a glass in Rigid Body simulation. Breaking glass in steps visually represented by spider cracks can be achieve just by image texture. All depend how slow or detailed animation should happen.

Comment: https://www.istockphoto.com/video/broken-screen-gm472856879-16865361

Comment: This reminds me great commercial :) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r8q-R9ZISac

Comment: @vklidu i figured out how to make the glass break, with the cell fracture modifier. Ill hand animate the parts that break and stuff. Is there a way to keyframe fractures so they happen one at a time? Im using the annotate tool and selecting that the the cell fracture menu.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Cell Fracture

- You can use object, particle system or Annotation Tool to initiate break structure. Directly in add-on specify Collection to store parts.
- Select shards, search *Rigid Body* > **Add Active**
- To protect shards from falling you would have to search *Rigid Body* > **Connect**
- or in this case could be enough just select border shards and set them under *Physics Properties > Rigid Body > Type* > *Passive**. On right-click *Copy to Selected*.
- Add *Sphere*, search *Rigid Body > Add Passive*, check **Animated**, add two anim keyframes

[image]

Since glass is freaked from beginning ... for animation you would have to render glass and hide generated shards for render (Outliner > Render Visibility - Camera icon that can be keyframed) up to break moment, at this frame switch Render Visibility for glass and shards.

### Fracture Modifier

There exist also great Fracture Modifier in special blender build (https://blender.community/c/graphicall) that keeps glass uncracked until collider breaks a glass.

### Fluid Sim

Then run *Fluid Sim*

[image]

[image]

Tip:

- To let fluid collide with all shards - in 3D viewport select one shard enable *Fluid > Effector*, *Select Similar* <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> > Collection, when all shards selected *Make Links* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> > *Modifiers*
- To keep shards frozen in initial position you can (in this case) change under *Scene Properties > Rigid Body World > Cache* change **Simulation Start Frame**

Comment: When I made the outlining shards passive and the inside shards active, the active parts fall out, i also have a bunch of shards so that could be why. How could i make everything stay in place until its visible? How i have it set up now is the cracked glass is invisible until the uncracked glass disappears and moves away so the fluid can move freely. Just figured it out, keyframe the dynamic. How can i copy keyframes to a bunch of objects at once? Thanks for the help btw.

Comment: To Copy keyframes from one object to others - Select all objects and last one with keyframes, pres Ctrl+L (Make Link) > "Animation Data"

Comment: Thank you again! I noticed that the shards only go a feet or two forwards then hit like an invisible wall. Do you know why that is?

Comment: should have mentioned, they fall down.

Comment: Fixed it, just had to add a passive "barrier" around it, in my case the hallway.  Everything seems to work perfectly now, beside the fluid leaking before it cracks and some parts of the meshing phasing through the wall.