# Anime ground break/shatter effect

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, texturing, objects, geometry-nodes

I've been messing around in Blender trying to recreate this ground breaking effect:
[image]

I've tried messing with shaders and displacement. I tried finding a way in geometry nodes.
I think im tackling the problem in a wrong way. Currently stuck with no idea on how to do it.
Any help/ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, i know you are new here, but you should focus on one problem, not on a whole animation. So where are you stuck at? You can ask as many questions as you want here, but you shouldn't ask on a whole animation...but just one part.

Comment: Its not the whole animation, its just that shatter effect. You see how the ground break? That is the only thing im trying to achieve

Comment: What about using cell fracture?

Comment: Cell fracture? I have not heard of that! Got a good resource for it?

Comment: It’s an add-on delivered with Blender. Just enable it

Comment: Thank you! I'll give it a try!

Comment: Jup! With some proper animation timing etc i can (mostly) get that effect! Thank you!!!

Comment: You are welcome

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/209264/can-i-make-a-sim-where-water-breaks-a-glass-window/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6686/how-do-i-make-an-object-bend-or-break-if-hit-with-sufficient-force/